# Flutter - One Signal Notifications Image in IOS

Tags: flutter, image, api, push-notification, onesignal

We have a mobile app that send notifications to users about upcoming campaigns from Server Side with One Signal API. We are going to design Notification pop up like Title - Subtitle - Image.

I can send Title and Subtitle with using `headings` and `contents` and also I can send Image to Android devices with `big_picture` but it cannot display Image in IOS devices. Do you know any way to solve this?

- I have tried `"ios_attachments": { "id": "IMAGE_URL"}` in the json body but that did't work.

Answer (score 0):

We use the OneSignal Rest API to send the push to our Android and iOS users, and here is the code snippet that works.

```
var message = {
            app_id: "xxxx",// your onesignal app id
            large_icon: message_body.image_url,
            contents: { "en": message_body.message }, //paragraph
            headings: { "en": message_body.title }, //title
            subtitle: { "en": message_body.subtitle },
            url: '', //link to website
            data: { 'TITLE': message_body.header_title, 'URL': message_body.url },
            ios_attachments: {'id': message_body.web_icon},//image to display below the text in notification on iOS app
            big_picture: message_body.web_icon,
            chrome_web_icon: message_body.web_icon, //image to display below text in notification for chrome on iOS
            include_player_ids: message_body.player_ids //["83e36362-a5e4-xxx-723bc736b07e"]//["d5c9a424-xxx-8b52-d68f70a61986","088b8bff-xxx-4905678b4999"]
        };
```